# How to get Current logged in user in Provider Hosted App with S2S and App-Only Policy?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

How can I get Current Logged in user of SharePoint Site in Provider Hosted App's code behind since the app is Provider Hosted, using S2S and with App-Only policy

I tried this:

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

I am getting all the time a user `i:0i.t|<some key>|app@sharepoint`. It looks like an user exclusive for the App as the definition in policy types says ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179892.aspx)).

I would like to have your help on this, since I need to work in app context with the user that is logged in Sharepoint Portal, and where is rendered the app into a page. I suppose I have to change the policy the app for a App+user policy, and if yes, how can I force this policy?

Comment: Which is the scope of the app? Do you have the read permission?

Comment: I have 2 scopes defined. Site Collection - Full Control, and Web - Full Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get SharePoint app identity if your app is provider hosted and app only. If this is Asp.Net MVC app, you can always get logged in user from HttpContext as below.
`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`
Pass this as parameter

```
User user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity won't be set if you're running an Azure Web App, because it would require Windows Authentication enabled in IIS which is not possible for Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.CurrentUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
```

Comment: I tried the code but gives me the same user that i mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

In your SharePoint app,locate Appmanifest.xml and uncheck **app only call** from permission tab, Use following code to read current logged in user

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
{
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Response.Write(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
}
```